# What date format is 636529536000000000?

Tags: asp.net, .net, datetime, formats

I have to maintain an ASPX page that increments the date/time by passing a value in the querystring in this format:

636529536000000000 in reference to 31 January 2018

636530400000000000 in reference to 01 February 2018

The url format is: `/reservas.aspx?t=636530400000000000`

What is this date/time format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It is the number of ticks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk(v=vs.110).aspx) where a tick is [one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx). The number of ticks is measured since the epoch [DateTime.MinValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) (12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001). For example:

```
new DateTime(636529536000000000).ToString("F", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

outputs:

> Wednesday, 31 January 2018 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Could be a number of days from certain date, similar to julian date calculation:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Julian_date_calculation

Potentially incorporating the time as well?

Without details of the code I cant really advise from a provided value.

Comment: I think is not an specific calculation because if you google 636530400000000000 it seems to be an standar of calendar format for certain pages.

Obviously I don't have the code.